# Count submitted queries

Tags: linq-to-sql, azure-sql-database, plinqo

So I'm using PLINQO Linq2Sql on a large project. I was wondering if there was any way I could count the number of queries that get submitted to the SqlServer via code using either PLINQO or Linq2Sql?

Like if I wrote the code

```
var a = Tables.Users.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Username == username);
var b = Tables.Apples.Where(x=>x.UID == a.UID).ToList();
var c = Tables.Pears.Where(x=>x.UID == a.UID);
```

The result would be `2` since the third one is still just an `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not something you want to do in a production environment.

I do not have a solution, but I guess you could start with the log property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx

and code something around it.

Comment: Thanks. That's kind of what I do now, was just hoping there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: What I do is use the SQL profiler during development, make sure I do not get n+1 queries or "weird" SQL